# I can't get call stack of optimized NDK app built by Clang

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, clang

I'm Jeonghun Lee of Pearlabyss.

I have encountered a very difficult problem to solve.

We are developing a android game with Clang 3.8 of NDK r12.

We start with a Native Activity project of Visual Studio 2015.

We are using Google Breakpad which is a crash report tool.

Our problem is that we can't get accurate call stack when we turn an optimization on.

In -O1 optimization, we can see only the name of crashed function.

In -O2 optimization, we can't see any function name.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably by Massive Logging in Logcat you can know at which point error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the stack trace from **logcat**, you can use the `ndk-stack` script that is part of NDK to resolve the line numbers of each address that appears in the log. The script uses `addr2line` under the hood, so you can run this utility manually if you prefer.